# Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit Error when trying to execute function on mainnet

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, ethers.js, hardhat

Hi i encountering this error when i want to execute smart contract onFlashLoan function:
Error:

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xA20f9C4905Ec7219b2Afe3B1ba95B4E708a48141","gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x06ddd0"},"to":"0x026b77a9aC8815C85B75d275103F8261BEe2Eb73","data":"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","accessList":null}, error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":34562,\"error\":{\"code\":3,\"data\":\"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b556e69737761705632526f757465723a20494e53554646494349454e545f4f55545055545f414d4f554e54000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\",\"message\":\"execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT\"}}","error":{"code":3,"data":"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b556e69737761705632526f757465723a20494e53554646494349454e545f4f55545055545f414d4f554e54000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"gas\":\"0x6ddd0\",\"from\":\"0xa20f9c4905ec7219b2afe3b1ba95b4e708a48141\",\"to\":\"0x026b77a9ac8815c85b75d275103f8261bee2eb73\",\"data\":\"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\"}],\"id\":34562,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/aec2f0c72c444f25bd632d074dcf9a85"}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at checkError (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:78:20)
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:642:20)
    at step (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  method: 'estimateGas',
  transaction: {
    from: '0xA20f9C4905Ec7219b2Afe3B1ba95B4E708a48141',
    gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x06ddd0', _isBigNumber: true },
7465723a20494e53554646494349454e545f4f55545055545f414d4f554e54000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\",\"message\":\"execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT\"}}", error={"code":3,"data":"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b556e69737761705632526f757465723a20494e53554646494349454e545f4f55545055545f414d4f554e54000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"gas\":\"0x6ddd0\",\"from\":\"0xa20f9c4905ec7219b2afe3b1ba95b4e708a48141\",\"to\":\"0x026b77a9ac8815c85b75d275103f8261bee2eb73\",\"data\":\"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\"}],\"id\":34562,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/aec2f0c72c444f25bd632d074dcf9a85", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
      at Logger.makeError (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
      at E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\src.ts\index.ts:341:28
      at step (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)
      at Object.next (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
      at fulfilled (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:5:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    reason: 'processing response error',
    code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
    body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":34562,"error":{"code":3,"data":"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b556e69737761705632526f757465723a20494e53554646494349454e545f4f55545055545f414d4f554e54000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","message":"execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT"}}',
    error: Error: execution reverted: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT
        at getResult (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:142:28)
        at processJsonFunc (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\src.ts\index.ts:383:22)
        at E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\src.ts\index.ts:320:42
        at step (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)
        at Object.next (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
        at fulfilled (E:\SandwitchV1\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:5:58)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      code: 3,
      data: '0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b556e69737761705632526f757465723a20494e53554646494349454e545f4f55545055545f414d4f554e54000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    },
    requestBody: '{"method":"eth_estimateGas","params":[{"gas":"0x6ddd0","from":"0xa20f9c4905ec7219b2afe3b1ba95b4e708a48141","to":"0x026b77a9ac8815c85b75d275103f8261bee2eb73","data":"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"}],"id":34562,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
    requestMethod: 'POST',
    url: 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/aec2f0c72c444f25bd632d074dcf9a85'
  }
}
```

Smart contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

interface IERC3156FlashBorrower {
    function onFlashLoan(
        address initiator,
        address token,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 fee,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external returns (bytes32);
}

contract FlashBorrower2 is Context, ReentrancyGuard, IERC3156FlashBorrower {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    address private owner;
    address USDC = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48;
    uint256 public constant MAX_INT = type(uint256).max;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier OnlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function onFlashLoan(
        address initiator,
        address token,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 fee,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external override nonReentrant returns (bytes32) {
        IERC20(token).approve(msg.sender, MAX_INT);
        uint256 amountOutExpected;
        uint256 amountOutExpected2;
        (amountOutExpected, amountOutExpected2) = abi.decode(
            data,
            (uint256, uint256)
        );
        address UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
        address SUSHISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F;

        IUniswapV2Router02 uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(
            UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS
        );
        IUniswapV2Router02 sushiSwapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(
            SUSHISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS
        );

        address[] memory path2 = new address[](2);
        path2[0] = token;
        path2[1] = USDC;

        sushiSwapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            amount,
            amountOutExpected,
            path2,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = USDC;
        path[1] = token;

        uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            IERC20(USDC).balanceOf(address(this)),
            amountOutExpected2,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );

        return keccak256("ERC3156FlashBorrower.onFlashLoan");
    }

    function withdrawWETH(address WETH) external OnlyOwner {
        require(
            IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(address(this)) > 0,
            "No funds to withdraw"
        );
        IERC20(WETH).transfer(owner, IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(address(this)));
    }
}
```

Code that executing function and calculating gas

```
let amountETH = ethers.utils.parseUnits("500", "ether");
const conadd= "contract address"
const token = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2";
   const feeData = await provider.getFeeData();
    const gasPrice = await feeData.gasPrice;
    let gasPriceGwei = await ethers.utils.formatUnits(gasPrice, "gwei");
    let newGasPriceGwei = parseFloat(gasPriceGwei) + 6;
    let newGasPriceGwei2 = newGasPriceGwei.toFixed(6);

    let newGasPriceWei = ethers.utils.parseUnits(
      newGasPriceGwei2.toString(),
      "gwei"
    );

 let formattedEX1S = ethers.utils.parseUnits(EX1S.toString(), "ether");
      let formattedEX2S = ethers.utils.parseUnits(EX2S.toString(), "ether");
      let dataF = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
        ["uint256", "uint256"],
        [formattedEX1S, formattedEX2S]
      );

      const gasEstimateF = await contract.estimateGas.onFlashLoan(
        conadd,
        token,
        amountETH,
        0,
        dataF,
        { gasLimit: 450000 }
      );
      console.log("estimated gas:" + gasEstimateF);

      const gasEstimateWithBuffer = gasEstimateF.mul(120).div(100);
      console.log("estimated gas with buffer:" + gasEstimateWithBuffer);

      const tx = await contract.onFlashLoan(
        conadd,
        token,
        amountETH,
        0,
        dataF,
        {
          gasLimit: gasEstimateWithBuffer,
          gasPrice: newGasPriceWei,
        }
      );
```